# Error in recruiting app

Tags: force.com

i am facing an[image] error in creating Phil katz and others as a user with standard profile, because in profile section there is no standard profile.

Comment: What error you are getting? Which profile do you want to assigned to Phil katz?

Comment: As i have mentioned that standard profile does not show up in profile box while creating phil katz as a user.

Comment: Do you have salesforce in user licenses drop down?

Comment: salesforce license is full, so i deactivated one salesforce license but the problem remain unsolved